# Getting a corrupted Powerpoint file that is created using OOXML and C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

My code opens a Powerpoint presentation, adds some shapes to that, saves it and then inserts that presentation into another final presentation file. It works fine and I get not error using the OOXML validator object. However, when I open the final presentation, Power Point gives me the option to repair the file because it is corrupted.

My code to create the shapes is located in this link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/thread/4a2f50df-7e75-435c-9974-7066e125dd03

My code to copy one presentation into another is located in this link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lv-LV/oxmlsdk/thread/8d014ba5-3566-4d44-ac22-229f2bbd442a

I have been dealing with this error for months.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the file, you create, then let PowerPoint repair one of the copies and compare the two files (compare the xml with an editor or fc) and check what PowerPoint has changed? Maybe that gives you a hint in the right direction ...

Comment: Yes I did it, but not clear solution. Please check my comments below. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd encourage you to use Open XML 2.0 SDK Productivity Tool, which is part of OpenXML SDK - it helped me to find where are the problems in my resulting files. Power Point should tell around which node the problem exists. Unfortunately, the tool won't tell you if there is an error if trying to verify the root node - you'd have to browse the xml tree a little, maybe, to find exact problem.

Comment: After comparing files, the corrupted one does not shows the following lines:

/ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout100.xml
/ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout101.xml

/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout100.xml
/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout101.xml

/ppt/slideMasters/_rels/slideMaster10.xml.rel
/ppt/slideMasters/_rels/slideMaster11.xml.rel

/ppt/slideMasters/slideMaster10.xml
/ppt/slideMasters/slideMaster11.xml

/ppt/slides/_rels/slide10.xml.rels
/ppt/slides/_rels/slide11.xml.rels

/ppt/slides/slide10.xml
/ppt/slides/slide11.xml

/ppt/theme/theme10.xml
/ppt/theme/theme11.xml

Comment: What calls my attention is the fact that if the final presentation has 10 slides or less, it does not get corrupted. However, if it has 11 or more it does get corrupted. Any thoughts?

Comment: Another thing I noticed after my comparison is the /docPros/app.xml shows 1 slide for the corrupted file and 11 for the repaired one: 
<Paragraphs>
  0
</Paragraphs>
<Slides>
  1
</Slides> The repaired one: <Paragraphs>
  1600
</Paragraphs>
<Slides>
  11
</Slides>